# What is this Component labelled VR1

Tags: identification, thermistor

My Falmec Rangehood died.  It looks like a component has burst on the controller board.  There is actually smoke marks on the cover of the board.

It is next to F1 (non-existent), at the power entry.  I am assuming that F1 was a old fashioned fuse.  So this VR1 must be a replacement for over-voltage or temperature detection and shutdown.

With it dead, there is no power to the rest of the circuitry.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it is a varistor. usually it is an overvoltage problem.

Comment: Thats what I suspected.  I can't trace the tracks without cleaning the board.  Does it go across the mains or does it go in series on Live.  I want to get it working so we can use the kitchen while I find the part.  Which is hard in NZ.  There wont be another issue.  Yesterday while the solar installers were tracing the cables with the power on, one cable was loose and came out and shorted against something.  Three items in the house have died, probably got 400V (as we have 3 phase).  It is very strange that everything else is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a varistor and although the circuit is not completely shown it seems that the fuse is blown up by the varistor following an overvoltage as it might be mounted like this:

[image]

Comment: That makes sense.  I had assumed that the fuse was missing, but maybe its vaporised totally.

Comment: Can I ask, what software you used to draw that.

Comment: RohitGupta I started using circuit lab but since I couldn't find a varistor symbol and to make it fast I completed it by hand. sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: On the contrary, I liked the look of it compared to what I have been using.